# Google +1 button does not appear in Chrome when inside an iframe

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-plus-one

Since a few days the Google+1 button doesn't show up on my sites anymore.

I have placed the Google+1 code in an iframe, together with facebook, twitter etc buttons.

This worked fine till a few days ago.

The problem is only when I use Google Chrome. FF, safari and IE work fine. I'm using Chrome 13. I've had other people test this, and everybody on Chrome is now getting problems with the +1 button, if its placed inside an Iframe.

Any ideas how to fix this, without removing the Iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been fixed by Google. It was a bug in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with our Google+1 buttons disappearing in Chrome only, no problems in FF, IE, Safari. The issue was related to how we were passing a custom URL to google's API. If you post some code here, it might help.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with any form of the +1 button (e.g. even default). It'll appear in Safari / FF but not Chrome so I think it isn't related just to a custom URL.

Default code: http://jsfiddle.net/6PKmc/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from chrome, it doesn't run javascript inside iframe.  The solution is a workaround from here : http://www.google.vu/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=5e2fab7a54e9587e&hl=en